# Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence with limit $\alpha$, and define $b_n=a_{n+1}$ where $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Show that $\{b_n\}\rightarrow \alpha$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence with limit $\alpha$, and define $b_n=a_{n+1}$ where $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Show that $\{b_n\}\rightarrow \alpha$.

What I have:

Since $\{a_n\}\rightarrow \alpha$ we know that for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|a_n-\alpha|<\epsilon$ for all $n\geq N$.

I'm stuck trying to figure the rest out. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Since $\{a_n\}\rightarrow \alpha$ we know that for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N_1\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|a_n-\alpha|<\epsilon$ for all $n\geq N_1$. Let $N=N_1-1$. Then $\forall n\ge N$, $|b_n-\alpha|=|a_{n+1}-\alpha|<\epsilon$.

Comment: Why do we let $N=N_1-1$?

Comment: In fact you can let $N$ be any integer $\ge N_1-1$. Then $n>N$ implies $n+1>N_1$ and so $|a_{n+1}-\alpha|<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 2):

$|b_n-a|\leq |b_n-a_n|+|a_n-a|=|a_{n+1}-a_n|+|a_n-a|\to 0+0$ because $\{a_n\}$ is Cauchy as Mhenni told. With this way you don't mess up with epsilon definition and you can solve many problems like that.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $a_n \rightarrow a$ as $n \to \infty$ we have that,

Let $\epsilon >0, \exists N_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n \geq N_1, |a_n -a|<\epsilon/2$.

Also $\exists N_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ , such that for all $n,m \geq N_2$ $|a_n-a_m|=|a_n-a+a-a_m| \leq |a_n-a|+|a_m-a|<\epsilon/4+\epsilon/4<\epsilon/2$

So,for $n \geq \max \{N_1,N_2 \} $  $|a_{n+1}-a|=|a_{n+1}-a_n+a_n-a|\leq |a_{n+1}-a_n| + |a_n-a|< \epsilon/2+ \epsilon/2 =\epsilon$